# CXF 3.0 and Spring - No message body reader has been found for response Class

Tags: json, spring, cxf, jax-rs

I'm writing a JSX-RS based Spring+CXF client for a service that sends a simple response as below.

**JSON : Response**

```
{
    "message": "Hey Karthik"
}
```

**I have the following configuration in my spring.xml:**

```
<jaxrs:providers>
<bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider">
<property name="dropRootElement" value="true" />
</bean>
</jaxrs:providers>
```

My entity class looks like this

```
@XmlRootElement
public class HiModel {

    private String message;

    public HiModel(){}
    .
    .
    .
}
```

**My JAX-RS client is like this:**

```
@Test
public void getMessage(){
    WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8182");
    client.path("hiService/sayHi/hi");
   client.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    Response r = client.get();
    System.out.println(r.readEntity(HiModel.class));

}
```

I get the error : **No message body reader has been found for class com.karthik.model.HiModel, ContentType: application/json**

How do I resolve it? There are lots of questions with the method I chose to write as client, but I first need to get this resolved. Please help.

**EDIT 1 : I can resolve it by**

```
System.out.println(r.readEntity(String.class));
```

But, How do I resolve it with the entity as ***HiModel.class***

Comment: Your question is confusing, please explain exactly what is your problem

Comment: Try creating a `List` and add a `JSONProvider` to the list. Then `WebClient.create("...", list);`

Comment: Or `WebClient.create("...", locationOfConfigFile);`. See the [`WebClient`](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/WebClient.html) API

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps someone. I had similar scenario, and I managed to solve it using Jackson JSON library. Using your example:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8182/hiService/sayHi/hi");
Response r = client.accept("application/json").get();       
MappingJsonFactory factory = new MappingJsonFactory();
JsonParser parser = factory.createJsonParser((InputStream)r.getEntity());
HiModel hiModel= parser.readValueAs(HiModel.class);
```

Very similar test is actually present within Apache CXF JAX-RS archetype.

Answer (score 2):

Add it to the webclient object.

`List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<>();
        // add custom providers if any
        providers.add(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider());
        WebClient client = WebClient.create(ENDPOINT_ADDRESS,providers);`

If you are not using spring to configure cxf then:

1) in Web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet
    </servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.jaxrs.JaxRsConfigApplication
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

2) On the JaxRsConfigApplication.java

```
public class JaxRsConfigApplication extends Application {


@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<>();
    resources.add(ServicioPistaRest.class);
    resources.add(ConsultarDatosSolicitud.class);
     return resources;
}


@Override
public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    Set<Object> classes = new HashSet<>();
    JacksonJaxbJsonProvider jacksonJaxbJsonProvider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider();
    classes.add(jacksonJaxbJsonProvider);
    return classes;
}
```

}